# Sorting lists, assigning names to indexes and printing them

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

is there a way to count letters in this sentence, and print the most used ones?(like: G A D F J N) I know how to count them and sort thwm but cant figure out how to print the letters instead of th ordered numbers.(btw all letters need to be printed in the result)

```
#example
input: Hello you!
Output: O L H E Y U # <-at least 1 letter# A B C D#<- The rest of the letters
```

What im trying:

```
Pismenka = [0] *26
Veta = input()
For i in veta:
       Pismenka[ord(i-97)]+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for you;

```py
import re

text = "Hello you!"

# I lowered capitalized characters because if there was 'H' and 'h',
# the program would have counted these two as two different letters.
text = text.lower()

letters = {}

#We search for '\w' which means only latin characters.
for i in re.findall(r"\w", text):
    if i not in letters:
        letters[i] = 1
    else:
        letters[i] += 1

# We sort the items according to the count of letters.
sortedByCount = dict(sorted(letters.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))

# We get only the keys, 'letters' out of the dictionary and concatnate with spaces.
output = " ".join(sortedByCount.keys())
```

**Output:**

```py
l o h e y u
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would look for a magic optimized function already coded in the Python jungle. I'm sure this question was already raised and optimized.

If I had to do it myself from a preliminary unoptimized thought I would do something like this:

```
testString = 'Hello sss Test'
from collections import OrderedDict
alreadyTested = OrderedDict()
for c in testString:
    if c not in alreadyTested:
        alreadyTested[c] = testString.count(c)       
for c in sorted(alreadyTested,key=alreadyTested.__getitem__,reverse=True):
    print(c,alreadyTested[c])
```

the use of an ordered dictionary is required if you want letters with the same occurrence number to remain in appearance order. Otherwise you can use a basic dictionary.